# How to add a "background-image" to an "img" tag and switch display on mouseover?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, mouseover

I have an `img` tag like this (and I can't use a container)

```
<img src="https://example.com/first-image.jpg" class="my-image">
```

And I would like to display a second image instead of the first one on mouseover using only CSS. Maybe doing something like this:

```
.my-image:hover {
    background-image: url("https://example.com/second-image.jpg");
}
```

I'm not sure if it that's possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1: HTML can be edited

You can do it by not using the src attribute and set the default image in your CSS, then change it on hover like so:

```
.my-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://....jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.my-image:hover {
  background-image: url(https://....jpg);
}
```

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/86ujL1dv/

Note that modern browsers don't load images until they're needed, so there will be a slight delay on the first hover, as the user's browser will load the second picture.

### Solution 2: HTML cannot be edited

It's a bit of a hack, but you can set the size of the img to zero, and use padding to make it look the same, then use the `background-image` property, like so:

```
.my-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.my-image:hover {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4017166/pexels-photo-4017166.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
}
```

See live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1bo7L89w/

Comment: The "img" has the first image in "src", not in "background-image". So, thanks, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Marcel You didn't make clear that the HTML could not be modified. In that case, I'm adding another answer

Comment: Will, do you know if there is a way to display both images at the same time? I mean, the first image would be a normal image and the second one a small icon. Then on mouseover it would be displayed the icon over the first image.

Comment: @Marcel I don't think that's possible without modifying the HTML. You could use pseudo-elements (like `:after` or `:before`) if it was a different tag, but `<img>` does not allow pseudo-elements.